# In Firefox 4, how do I get the RSS feed button back?

Tags: rss, gui, firefox

I've upgraded to Firefox 4 and the RSS feed button was removed from the address bar! How do I get it back?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right-click the toolbar and select `Customize`. A `Subscribe` icon should be available. Drag it to the desired location on the toolbar, and then select Done to close the `Customize Toolbar` window.

Comment: Doesn't really jive with the minimalist look of FF4, but at least it grays-out when no feed is available!

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks for that. And without relying on any third-party stuff.

Answer (score 13):

**[RSS Icon In Awesombar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rss-icon-in-awesombar/)** - Mozilla Addons.

> Add RSS icon back into location bar (URL) in Firefox 4.0. This icon was showed in Firefox 3.5/3.6 by default when page offered feeds.

[image]

Note: I am not in any way, shape, or form affiliated with this addon/software.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can also use https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/rss-icon/
which uses a new look. (Sorry no image here, since I'm new)</strike>
Another user reported, that this addon seems buggy, so:

Instead use this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/rss-icon-in-awesombar/ as the last user already recommended.

Note: I am not in any way, shape, or form affiliated with this addon/software.